# How do we set required for new & optional for existing fields - when adding basic field to content type?

Tags: entities

### How do we set required for new & optional for existing fields - when adding  basic field to content type?

When using Drupal 8 following this how to article shows the steps to take to add a basic field to content types. https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-fields.html

What I want to learn how to accomplish is to make the new field "Required" for all newly created content types however for existing content I want the field to be optional.

In the admin I see the `required` checkbox however this will make all of them required. Below is an image of what I am viewing:
[image]

Any & all feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_form_alter or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter to set require for that field.

```
 
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  if ($entity->isNew()) {
    $form['my_field']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

And, not set the field 'my_field' as required field.
Not tested, but it is a way to go.

Comment: You’ll want to narrow this down by content type or you will get warnings/errors.